# Customize a class of a library

Tags: python

I am using a Python library that has one function that I would need to customize.

That is not a problem, since I can make my own edited version like this:

```
from coolLibrary import originalclass

class myclass(originalclass):
    whatever...
```

The problem that I am facing now, is that the library uses this `originalclass` in multiple locations. Is there a way to tell the library to use `myclass` everywhere instead of `originalclass`?

My goal would be to have a custom code without editing the original code so the library can be updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `coolLibrary.originalclass` has explicit references to itself:

```
# coolLibrary.py
class originalclass:
    def foo(self):
        print('original foo')

    def bar(self):
        originalclass.foo(self)
```

such that:

```
# main.py
import coolLibrary

class myclass(coolLibrary.originalclass):
    def foo(self):
        print('custom foo')

myclass().bar()
```

outputs:

```
original foo
```

You can patch `coolLibrary.originalclass` with your custom class after the custom class is defined:

```
coolLibrary.originalclass = myclass
```

so that:

```
myclass().bar()
```

would then output:

```
custom foo
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing1/JollyHumiliatingTabs

Note that patching the original class makes the behavior change global. If another module that also uses `coolLibrary.originalclass` depends on its original behavior in order to work, you may want to apply the patch to only the block of code that needs such a custom behavior. This can be done with the `unittest.mock.patch` context manager:

```
from unittest.mock import patch

with patch('coolLibrary.originalclass', myclass):
    myclass().bar()
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very cool.. On the same topic, is it possible to add a custom function to a class instead of overwriting? For example, if i woult like to have `myclass().myNewFunction()` and have this new function have relative paths as if it was written inside the class?

Answer (score 0):

In short, no, there isn't. You would have to overwrite all references of originalclass with myclass in the original code, or simply apply your changes directly to originalclass.
If you're trying to preprocess or handle data, it could be a good choice to use a decorator in your case.

Comment: or just rename the class accordingly